# .htaccess home configuration

Tags: htaccess

How to configure .htaccess to this:
I need that my home page is http://mydomain.cl/c/news/ but I cant do this.
Anyone want help me please?
Thanks!

Now, my htaccess is :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php[L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain/.cl/c/news/.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Please explain **why** this helps the OP – in an [edit] to your answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit **wp-config.php** and add this line :

```
define('WP_HOME', 'http://your-domain.com/news');
```